# What's wrong with this simple SQL-based ETL solution?

Tags: relational-database, etl, data-warehouse

We use Informatica PowerCenter to move data mostly from other relational databases into our data warehouse. I've come
up with a simple algorithm to move data into a star schema or any materialized view using change data capture, and
would like to know what's wrong with it so I can better understand the appeal of tools such as Informatica.

Assumptions:

- We have a CDC message channel through which individual insert/update/delete events arrive.
- We've defined the materialized view of interest as an aggregate SQL query against the source tables. In other words, it's
  a SQL query that contains a GROUP BY expression. Therefore, the materialized view is guaranteed to have a consistent
  granularity, and the contents of the GROUP BY expression can be treated as its primary key.

The algorithm:

- A CDC message comes over the channel. A source table row was changed:

  We loop through any queries that depend on this table. For every query, we determine whether the table is 'primary'
  or 'non-primary' for this particular query - e.g. whether a value from this table was used in the query's GROUP BY
  expression. In other words, we determine whether the PK of the materialized view depends on this table directly.

  - A primary table was changed:

    - A primary table row was inserted with the value P=p:

      - Insert the raw row into our mirror of the source table.
      - Run the query of interest with the filter WHERE P=p and find the affected rows.
      - Insert the affected rows into our materialized view table.
    - A primary table row was updated with the value P=p1 changing to P=p2:

      We split this into two messages: DROP P=p1 (see below) and INSERT P=p2 (see above).
    - A primary table row was with the value P=p was deleted:

      - Run the query of interest with selecting just the PK values and the filter WHERE P=p to find the
        affected PK values (pk1, pk2, ..., pkn).
      - Drop the raw row of our mirror of the source table.
      - Drop the rows WHERE PK IN (pk1, pk2, ..., pkn) from the materialized view table.
  - A non-primary table was changed:

    - A non-primary table row was inserted with the relevant value V=v:

      - Insert the raw row into our mirror of the source table.
      - Run the query of interest with the filter WHERE V=v and find the affected PK values (pk1, pk2, ..., pkn).
      - Run the query of interest with the filter WHERE PK in (pk1, pk2, ..., pkn) and update these rows
        in the materialized view table.
    - A non-primary table row was updated with the relevant value changed from V=v1 to V=v2:

      We split this into two messages: DROP V=v1 (see below) and INSERT V=v2 (see above).
    - A non-primary table row with the relevant value V=v was deleted:

      - Run the query of interest with selecting just the PK values and the filter WHERE V=v to find the
        affected PK values (pk1, pk2, ..., pkn).
      - Drop the raw row from our mirror of the source table.
      - Run the query of interest with the filter WHERE PK in (pk1, pk2, ..., pkn) and update these rows
        in the materialized view table.

Making it even better:

- Any updates of the materialized view table can themselves be converted into CDC messages. This would allow for
  recursive updates to materialized views that depend on other materialized views.

If such a solution could actually work and be fast and scalable, it could solve 80% of our ETL problems. However,
I can't be the first person to think of such a naive approach, so please do tell me why this can't work.

Comment: Hi - you are asking for an opinion so your question is not really in scope for this forum. However, lots of people write their own ETL frameworks (normally in Python these days) and their are good and bad reasons for doing so. Have a think about how you would manage complex data transformations, data lineage, data governance, data quality, different types of source data, etc. etc. using your framework

Comment: Thanks for responding, @NickW!

Comment: To be more specific, I'm looking for logic errors and performance errors (is there a full table scan somewhere that I missed?) in my algorithm (this is really just an algorithm and not a full framework), which I think can be answered objectively. I can't think of a reason why the algorithm wouldn't work with arbitrarily complex data transformations, as long as there's a GROUP BY clause. Data lineage is trivial since the algorithm already relies on it. Other issues you raised are out of scope since this is not a full framework.

Comment: Hi - happy to be proved wrong but I doubt you'll get a useful response from this site as it is really here for helping with actual coding issues rather than pseudo-code/theoretical algorithms. Feel free to implement an actual solution based on your algorithm and then come back with specific questions if something is not working as expected and you need help resolving it

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this in the future, [differential dataflow](https://github.com/timelydataflow/differential-dataflow/) is a much better solution than what I posted. There's an open-source SQL-like implementation of differential dataflow called [Materialize](https://github.com/MaterializeInc/materialize).